# Is there a reference Eo lexicon for version control?

Tags: translation, resources

[Version control systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) are tools used in software engineering. They come with a specific vocabulary which is sometimes difficult to translate unambiguously.

[Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=version%20control) translates *version control system* as *versikontrola sistemo*, while [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versitena_sistemo) proposes *versitena sistemo*. The latter seems more correct to me, since *to control* does not translate as *kontroli*. But more generally, I could not find a comprehensive and reliable
Esperanto lexicon on this field. Komputeko lacks a lot of basic terms. [A
translation](https://git-scm.com/book/eo/) of a Git handbook has been started, but for now it is very limited. Have I missed a better source?

Some terms have a straightforward translation:

- version: *versio*
- branch: *branĉo*
- to pull: *tiri*
- to push: *puŝi*
- to clone: *kloni*

For others, I have doubts:

- repository: *deponejo*?
- to commit: *konfidi*, *submeti*?
- pull request: *tirpeto*, *aldonpeto*?
- to fork: *forki*, *disbranĉi*?
- to merge: *kunfandi*, *kunfluigi*?
- working copy: *labora kopio*, *laborkopio*?
- to checkout: ?

Answer (score 5):

TLDR; Try looking at examples of people discussing VCS in Esperanto.

After looking at the Github page for Pasporta Servo, I found some ways of expressing these terms. They are not all perfect translations, but they are at least understood.

- versio -> version
- branĉo -> branch
- tiri -> pull
- puŝi -> push
- deponejo -> repository
- ŝanĝaro / [enmeto](https://gitter.im/tejo-esperanto/pasportaservo?at=569ffb06a03e28ad1adfe663) -> commit. It seems there is not a widely used translation.
- [rebazi](https://gitter.im/tejo-esperanto/pasportaservo?at=584ebe240da034021b9da8a9%60) -> rebase
- peti tiron -> pull request

For all the other verbs, I have uncommonly seen people use *fari* followed by a command. Here's an example from gitter:

> mi faris `git checkout -b prod`